# SQL запрос, который разделяет один столбец на множество

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите, как сформировать запрос в SQL. Есть в таблице поле типа `Varchar`, в котором содержится следующий текст:

> 1670 2080|Изделие: Обычная балконная дверь штульповая|Древесина: Лиственница цельная|Профиль: IV-68|Цвет снаружи: GW306 ID7006 LW700 62.05.55-50% 2 слоя(СЛМ)|Цвет внутри: GW306 ID7006 LW700 62.05.55-50% 2 слоя(СЛМ)|Профиль створки: Скос 20*|Профиль шт...

Мне нужен SQL запрос, который выводил бы данные такого формата в отдельные поля, разделяя строку по символу `|`:

- поле 1 — `1670 2080`,
- поле 2 — `Изделие: Обычная балконная дверь штульповая` и так далее.

Comment: Исходная строка имеет фиксированное количество элементов? Т.е. количество разделителей "|" всегда одно и то же?

Comment: sql нам дана чтобы хранить **структурированные** данные, а не чтобы туда засовывать cvs.

Comment: @kadekin778 единственное, что можно здесь сказать - вы выбрали крайне неудачную структуру для хранения данных. Сложно представить, в какой ситуации подобное откровенно кривое решение может быть полезно. Поэтому единственный совет в данной ситуации - исправить структуру таблицы (или всей базы) на более адекватную и отталкиваться уже от полученного результата. Думаю, любые доработки существующей структуры приведут только к неприятным последствиям

Comment: Количество разделителей вариативное.
   Не я туда так данные засовываю. Это программа так их записывает. А я пытаюсь с MSQ переписать в FIREBIRD и работать с этими данными.

Answer (score 9):

Прямо сразу нарушение 1NF (первой нормальной формы) при хранение информации. Базы данных и SQL не предназначены для данных манипуляций с данными. Решением данного вопроса будет приведение БД к первой нормальной форме или использовать костыль в виде пользовательской функции на T-SQL.

Запрос в поисковик "TSQL split string" выдаст множество вариантов, ну например такой:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX('|', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX('|', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END

Ну и использование:

SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring('1670 2080|Изделие: Обычная балконная дверь штульповая|Древесина: Лиственница цельная|Профиль: IV-68|Цвет снаружи: GW306 ID7006 LW700 62.05.55-50% 2 слоя(СЛМ)')
```

Comment: думаю, тут есть одна потенциальная проблема - если таблица создана подобным образом, то скорее всего куча аналогичных проблем присутствует и в самом коде приложения. Я более чем уверен, что любое изменение структуры БД повлечет за собой миллион правок в коде приложения. Впрочем, это нисколько не является минусом вашего ответа

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите еще как теперь это применить в Delphi.
 Где нужно прописать CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )

Comment: @kadekin778, в базе данных MS SQL есть возможность писать пользовательские функции, которые сохраняются в самой базе данных и потом вызываются по требованию. Достаточно применить один раз CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring... запрос к БД любым способом(из делфи или через SQL SMS) и эта функция там останется сохраненной.

В остальном уже свободно используется только dbo.splitstring() как обычная функция, которой передается нужная строка символов. Можно даже подзапросом ее достать:
SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring((SELECT <поле> FROM <таблица> WHERE uid=1))

Comment: в MS SQL я знаю, что так возможно, а как в FIREBIRD прописать эту функцию

Comment: С Firebird не работал, но все тот же запрос в поисковик "firebird split string" выдал такой вариант(нужно только запятую поменять на нужный символ '|'): [stackoverflow - split comma separated string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056507/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-inside-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1):

Лично мне, последнее время понравилась винча  **XML**  из MSSQL, возможны так же другие варианты представления данных, я из вопроса понял что надо поделить на поля а не на записям. Могу написать оба варианта. Оговорюсь только что есть ограничения на вход (там знаки `<>& ) А в большинстве случаев работает хорошо. Скорость xml сравнима с скоростью работы функции, пожалуй в 1,5-2р медленнее, зато просто и меньше кода.

```
declare @c char(1000)
set @c =  '1670 2080|Изделие: Обычная балконная дверь  штульповая|Древесина: Лиственница цельная|Профиль: IV-68|Цвет снаружи: GW306 ID7006 LW700 62.05.55-50% 2 слоя(СЛМ)|Цвет внутри: GW306 ID7006 LW700 62.05.55-50% 2 слоя(СЛМ)|Профиль створки: Скос 20*|Профиль шт.'
select  x.value('(/a)[1]', 'varchar(50)') a1 ,
 x.value('(/a)[2]', 'varchar(50)')  a2,
 x.value('(/a)[3]', 'varchar(50)') a3,
 x.value('(/a)[4]', 'varchar(50)') a4,
 x.value('(/a)[5]', 'varchar(50)')  a5
from ( select  cast( '<a>' + replace(@c, '|' , '</a><a>') + '</a>' as   xml) x ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `persisted` вычисляемое `xml`-поле.
Так тоже можно выбрать, но это крайне медленно, так что и текст писать не буду.

Comment: Может текс напишите ?
>>Добавьте persisted вычисляемое xml-поле.
Так тоже можно выбрать, но это крайне медленно, так что и текст писать не буду.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к уже опубликованным ответам, вариант с рекурсивным ОТВ:

```
Declare @s  nvarchar(max) = '1670 2080|Изделие: Обычная балконная дверь штульповая|Древесина: Лиственница цельная|Профиль: IV-68|Цвет снаружи: GW306 ID7006 LW700 62.05.55-50% 2 слоя(СЛМ)'

;with cte (n)
       as 
         (
              select n = 0
              union all
              select n = n + 1 
              from cte
              where n <300
          )

    select substring(@s, n+1 ,lead(n-1, 1 , n*2) over (order by n)-n) as [Описание]
    from cte
    where substring(@s,n,1) ='|' or n = 0

option (maxrecursion 300)
```

тест

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вы решаете задачу не тем инструментом. Отдавайте данные в таком виде приложению, а уже в приложении перестраивайте результирующий массив.

Во-первых, даже если вы найдете решение на SQL, это будет костыль.

Во-вторых, у вас потенциальная проблема с делением — возможна ситуация, когда символ разделителя попадет в одну из частей записи, поэтому наверняка должна быть логика деления записи на компоненты. И лучше, если эта логика будет где-то рядом с кодом, отвечающим за слияние данных в одну строку.